# Making a link appear clicked temporarily in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I will try to explain this by example.

In HTML/CSS, let's say I have created a navigation bar, with one of the buttons called "home" that leads to the homepage. If I click on the home button, it changes in opacity from 1 to .5. While I stay on the homepage, it stays .5, but once I leave the homepage to, let's say, the "directions" page, the home button will change back to opacity of 1, and now the "directions" button is opacity .5.

So, how do I set up the button so that once clicked, it will change opacity, but once I leave the page it led me to, it changes back?

Currently, I have the following code in HTML for my navigation bar

```
<div id = "navigation">
  <ul>
  <li><a class = "nav" href = "Home.html">HOME</a><li>
  <li><a class = "nav" href = "index.html">BLOG</a><li>
  <li><a class = "nav" href = "thekids.html">KIDS</a><li>
  <li><a class = "nav" href = "Gallery.html">GALLERY</a><li>
  <li><a class = "nav" href = "http://www.mayorpotencial.org/">MP</a><li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then, in CSS, I have:

```
 #navigation {

  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;

}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;

}

a.nav {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  border: solid white 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.nav:hover {
  border: solid white 1px;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
   }
```

I was trying to use :visited, but since that pulls from history, once I click the button, the opacity remains even when I leave the page.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT

To better clarify what I need help with, please look at this website's nav bar below.

http://www.aiesec-cornell.org/

As you can see in this website, when you hover over one of the buttons, it changes in opacity. I want it so that after you click the button, it stays in a semi-transparent opacity. However, once you leave the page corresponding to that button, it returns to full opacity. This also means that the new button you clicked now changes in opacity as well.

How can I achieve this?

RESOLVED

In order to address the problem, I created an id = "active", and I added that id to whichever  element's page I am currently on. So, if I am on the homepage, I added it to the  element with the "home.html". The #active simply set the opacity to .5.

Comment: Did you try out my answer Yoo?

Comment: If you used a:active could you please mark my answer as correct, or whoever's answer it was that you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something along the lines that you are looking for? You want the link that is currently active to be at an opacity of 0.5?

**Edit:**

```
  a.current{
    opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

Just a quick edit to elaborate on this answer:

You can apply the  `.current` to each element that you want to be affected by the class, however if you are generating HTML dynamically rather than a static page then you should look into applying a check with JavaScript to know which nav button to add the class to.

**EG:**

You have a 'Home' and 'About' page. You'd need the script to detect which page you are on, then apply the `.current` class to the element dependant on the condition.

Second edit: I've just read your update and noticed that you've already done this. >_<

Comment: I have tried this, but it seems that :active only makes the button have .5 opacity while I am clicking it, but the opacity returns to normal once the click is finished. In other words, it stays semi-transparent for a short second while it is being clicked. So, unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since your NavBar is linked to all different `html`

Just create a `css` :

```
.selected {
    color: red;
}
```

And add this to the `a` (link) tag of the page (`html`) you're on at that time.

This will merely only change the color, but you can play around with opacity as well.

I feel that this is the simplest case you can play around with

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id = "navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a class = "nav" href = "Home.html">HOME</a><li>
    <li><a class = "nav" href = "index.html">BLOG</a><li>
    <li><a class = "nav" href = "thekids.html">KIDS</a><li>
    <li><a class = "nav" href = "Gallery.html">GALLERY</a><li>
    <li><a class = "nav" href = "http://www.mayorpotencial.org/">MP</a><li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

On every page, you set 'class="active"' to whatever navigation element is currently selected. Alternativly, you could use 'style="opacity: 0.5;', but that is not recommended.

Comment: When I am setting each page to "class = 'active'", how do I know which navigation element is currently selected? From what it looks like, what you put above would just make all the list elements permanently have an opacity of .5.

Comment: On each seperate HTML page, you must define the active class on whichever nav element you want to be selected